# Set hadoop configuration values in databricks job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have a job within databricks that requires some hadoop configuration values set. I have added entries to the "Spark Config" box

[image: Spark configuration in databricks]

However when I attempt to read the conf values they are not present in the hadoop configuration (`spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguraiton`), they only appear within the spark configuration (`spark.conf`)

Is there some way to propagate configuration from the spark configuration to the hadoop configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefix the configuration values with `spark.hadoop.` they will get passed into the hadoop configuration (`spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration`)

[image: Spark configuration in databricks]